# Pass select statement to Oracle PLSQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a PLSQL oracle function that accepts an array:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION CM.give_me_an_arrays (p_array IN num_array)   
RETURN VARCHAR2
IS 
 x   VARCHAR2 (512);
BEGIN
 x := '';
   FOR i IN 1 .. p_array.COUNT
   LOOP
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (p_array (i));
   END LOOP;

  RETURN x;
END;
/
```

I want to do that:

```
select CM.give_me_an_arrays(select COM.COM_ID 
                              from CM.XLP_SE_COMPONENT com  
                             where rownum < 10) 
  from dual
```

Any Ideas?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there a reason that the function needs to accept an array?  Could it accept a cursor instead?  That would generally make more sense if you want to pass in the result of a `SELECT` statement.  If you are taking the results of a query that returns 10 rows and producing a single aggregate result, are you sure that you don't want to write a custom aggregate function instead?

Answer (score 6):

You can do this as long as the array is an sql object (tested on 11gR2, should work on 10g):

```
SQL> create or replace type num_array is table of number;
  2  /

Type created.

SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION give_me_an_arrays (p_array IN num_array)
  2  RETURN VARCHAR2
  3  IS
  4   x   VARCHAR2 (512);
  5  BEGIN
  6   x := '';
  7     FOR i IN 1 .. p_array.COUNT
  8     LOOP
  9        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (p_array (i));
 10     END LOOP;
 11
 12    RETURN x;
 13  END;
 14  /

Function created.
```

You can call this function with the [COLLECT](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions031.htm#i1271564) aggregate function:

```
SQL> SELECT give_me_an_arrays((SELECT cast(collect(rownum) AS num_array) value
  2                              FROM dual
  3                            CONNECT BY level <= 10)) arr
  4    FROM dual;

ARR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------


1
2
[..]
10
```

In 9i (and maybe even 8i, can't test right now), COLLECT didn't exist but you could have used [MULTISET](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/operators006.htm#i1035617) instead:

```
SQL> SELECT give_me_an_arrays(cast(MULTISET(SELECT rownum value
  2                                           FROM dual
  3                                         CONNECT BY level <= 10) AS num_array)
  4                          ) arr
  5    FROM dual;

ARR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------


1
2
[..]
10
```